# Как передать в MessageBox на C++ интовое значение в текст

Tags: c++

Как можно передать в MessageBox интовое значение(в моем случае scrore)

```
MessageBox(NULL, (LPWSTR)to_string(score).c_str(), L"Проигрыш", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

Тут он просто выводит какие то символы.

Comment: вместо `(LPWSTR)to_string(score).c_str()` надо было сделать преобразование в широкую строку `::std::to_wstring(score).c_str()`. Тогда бы и ошибочный каст не понадобился.

Comment: Спасибо, а можно как то написать здесь не просто счет, а например Счет = (тут переменная scrore)

Comment: `(L"Счет = " + std::to_wstring(score)).c_str()`.